# How do you redirect to CGI only on a query?

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I'm replacing index.cgi of gitweb with a static index.html page.

However I don't want links to gitweb repositories to break, such as http://example.com/?p=foobar;

My non-working .htaccess currently looks like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p
RewriteRule ^/ /index.cgi
```

What am I missing?

Comment: When you say "non-working", what exactly do you see?  The only obvious thing I see missing is `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: Oh, also in a directory context (i.e. In a .htaccess file) URIs don't start with a slash.  In the server context they do.

Answer (score 0):

By my reading of the [RewriteRule docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) ("What is matched?" box), if your RewriteRule is in a Directory section or .htaccess file, then the leading `/` will be stripped away, so the pattern in your rule won't match.  You could try replacing the pattern by just `^`, i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^ /index.cgi
```

Comment: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. :(

Answer (score 0):

With that rule you will never be able to access the index.html page as the redirect will match anything.

You would need to do something along the lines of

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}      ^$
RewriteRule ^/                   /index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/                   /index.cgi
```

Which should work out similar to '*if you don't have a querystring go to index.html, otherwise go to index.cgi and pass the rest of the string along too!*'

Answer (score 0):

It will match any URI that is not index.cgi or index.html beginning with a **p** query string and rewrite it to your cgi.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p
RewriteRule !(index.cgi|index.html) /index.cgi [L]
```

The L option means that Apache stops processing rewrite rules.

Comment: Stangely I get a 404 The requested URL /srv/www/wac2tests/index.cgi was not found on this server.

Comment: but x220:~$ file /srv/www/wac2tests/index.cgi
/srv/www/wac2tests/index.cgi: symbolic link to `/srv/http/gitweb/gitweb.cgi'

Comment: That's not a URL, that's a file path.  I'm not sure why it's doing that.  I've seen Apache do that before but I can't remember what caused it.

Comment: Nice, short and sweet! QSA is unneeded and won't match example.com/ however.

Comment: actually this seems to redirect and file query string, even on say /ui/?foobar to /index.cgi... urgh :(